# Stata - Help for switchr command

Tags: regression, time-series, stata

I'm trying to perform a markov switching regression model in stata using the command *switchr*.

The command syntax is the following one:

*switchr eq1 eq2 [weight] [if exp] [, cluster(string) strata(string) sigequal tol(real) tout(integer) noisyn(integer) ]*

where *eq1* and *eq2* are the regime equation (the equation in which the variables coeffients change with respect to the regime) and the main equation (or classification equation). The stata help explains that equation as saying "
It must be defined by the user so that its dependent variable is a variable containing an initial guess of the
      partition of the observations into the two components.  This initial
      guess variable will be overwritten by switchr to contain the 
      probabilities that a given observation adheres to the first component 
      regression."

I'm not able to understand what the "main equation" means.

Which are the regression variables of the main equation?

I hope I was pretty clear asking this question. 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stata forums, you are asked to explain where user-written programs come from; that seems a good convention for CV too. As Pier Luigi should already know, `switchr` can be installed by typing in Stata

```
ssc install switchr
```

You are looking at the syntax statement from the help, but later in the help there is much more detail and examples of main and regime equations. Scroll down to the end to see. (A general tip with unfamiliar commands is to look at the examples first.)

Correct spelling is Markov.

Comment: Thank Nick for answering. I already saw the example, but it doesn't specify which kind of variables are in the main regression and how I can choose them. Surely the example is clear, but I really don't know how I can interpret that. It's for that I posted here.

Comment: There was also an article in 1998. That is accessible at http://www.stata.com/products/stb/journals/stb45.pdf If that doesn't help, I have never used the program, and you will need help from someone who has.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick.You're always kind and useful! thanks again!!